# Exception executing Rule Service running on ODM v8.10.2 (Rule server is deployed on Liberty 19.0.0.3)

Tags: ibm-odm

ODM Rule server app is deployed on Liberty Server 19.0.0.3. The rule service is being invoked from RestClient plugin in Firefox.
Getting following exception on liberty server running the rule server.

```
9/18/19 7:54:47:304 PDT] 000004ae com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl          I Create engine definition in debug from DSAR
[9/18/19 7:54:47:436 PDT] 000004ae com.ibm.rules.res.execution                                  E It was not possible to create the ruleset: /EDS_CustClientDUNSMailCountry_RuleApp/1.0/EDS_CustClientDUNSMailCountry/1.0.
com.ibm.rules.res.xu.internal.XUException: GBRXU0467E: The creation of EngineDefinition failed.
at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.java:89)
at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.XURulesetFactory.createDERuleset(XURulesetFactory.java:250)
at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.XURulesetFactory.createRuleset(XURulesetFactory.java:117)
at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.ruleset.internal.RulesetParsingWork.run(RulesetParsingWork.java:89)
at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.work.internal.ManagedThread.run(ManagedThread.java:36)
Caused by: com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoader$CreationException:   While applying business to execution (B2X) model mapping
GBREX0001E: Cannot find execution class 'com.ibm.rules.dmn.runtime.DateConverter' for translating business class 'com.ibm.rules.dmn.runtime.DateConverter'
GBREX0001E: Cannot find execution class 'myModel.odm.EDS_CustClientDUNSMailCountryDecision' for translating business class 'myModel.odm.EDS_CustClientDUNSMailCountryDecision'

at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.createEngineDefinitionInDebugFromDSAR(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:155)
at com.ibm.rules.engine.load.XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicLoaderImpl.java:66)
at com.ibm.rules.res.xu.engine.de.internal.XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.createEngineDefinition(XUEngineDynamicDefinitionFactory.java:82)
```

Thanks
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix with the help from a friend. If you download the rule app from decision center and manually deploy it on rule server this issue happens. The downloaded jar files miss the XOM objects. To fix that you need to deploy the rule app on to ruleserver from decision center. Once I did that the exception went away.

Thanks
Madhu